# Creating Info Window in CartoDB to scroll through features for different points with same geometry?

Tags: carto, infowindow

How do I create an info window where you can scroll through and see features for different points that have the same geometry? I am making a map of newspapers. For example, there's a cluster of 6 at New Orleans and 272 at New York. My info window only shows info for one newspaper even though there are obviously many more. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use **[CartoDB.js](https://github.com/cartodb/cartodb.js)**  ([link course](http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up.html))

There, you'd need to work with infowindow model and its templates.

If your scenario is with **public datasets**, you could use the next examples:

- [Infowindows with several layers](http://bl.ocks.org/xatpy/84b0ad64dc2ce7a4fcfd):wip
- [byndhack](http://byndhack.herokuapp.com/)

The *key* is to set a template calling the **API SQL** too. There, you could build that infowindow as you want.

Example:

```
 function main() {

    cartodb.createVis(map, 'youviz.json')
     .on('done', function(vis,layers) {
      var infowindow = layers[1].getSubLayer(0).infowindow
      infowindow.set('template', _.debounce(function(data) {
        var clickPosLatLng = this.model.get('latlng');
        var url = //Your sql query
        $.get(url, function(data) {
          var em = $('<div>');
          _.map(data.rows, function(r) { 
            var element = $('<li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">' + r.description + '</a></li>');
              em.append(element);
          });
          $('#mylist').append(em);
        });

        return $('#infowindow_template').html();
  }
```